# Web Service client - static versus dynamic

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jax-ws, cxf

I have a WSDL URI with me and I'm about to write a web service client to access the service. It seems we can create a static client or a dynamic client. For static clients, we create and compile the client stubs in advance and in the case of dynamic clients, the stubs are generated and invoked at runtime.

I would like to know about the practical scenarios where we choose dynamic clients over static clients. I understand that there is a performance penalty when creating the stubs at runtime in the case of dynamic clients. So, what are the use cases when we need a dynamic client?

Has anyone used dynamic invocation successfully in your projects/company?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was going to say it myself but remembered this text I came across, which I think has a clear description of the various techniques

http://searchsoa.techtarget.com/answer/Static-versus-dynamic-invocation-of-a-Web-service

So it is really down to you to decide which best suits your scenario, based on speed vs flexibility and simplicity vs complexity.

Comment: Thanks Peter. I've read that earlier however I was looking for a practical use case. In my case, I will be invoking the web service exactly once every day. So, I'm not sure if I have to choose static or dynamic method. It looks better not to have all the ugly stubs generated in advance. So, I want to know if dynamic invocation is something that is used successfully.